# How do force a text field to register a change that was done programmatically in JS

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I have a Chrome extension that fills out a text field on a website using

```
subjectField.value = "Text"
```

The field fills in however the form doesn't register as text being entered and doesn't allow the form to submit because there aren't enough characters in the field. It shows as 0/100. I have to enter an additional character manually to get it to register, which is less than ideal.

I tried triggering an 'onchanged' event to the field with no luck. Are there any other ways I can go about getting the field to recognize the text that was added to it via the extension?

Comment: isn't it a `change` event, not `onchanged` - how have you attempted this?

Comment: When I tried this [form](https://nory-soft.web.app/form.html), I was able to submit the form after registering in the text field with executeScript.
Please post your html and Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: assuming that `subjectField` is an istance of HTMLElement (an input in this case):

```
subjectField.value = "Text"
subjectField.dispatchEvent(new Event("input", { bubbles: true }))
```

Comment: This seems to have done the trick. Thanks!